# Auto-generate setters/getters with Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, auto-generate

I am unable to find a way to auto-generate getters and setters for a C++ class, using Qt Creator 2.3.1.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Do a right click on your member then `Refactor` then `Generate Getter and Setter member function` and you're done :)

[image: example]

---

On Qt Creator 3.2.x, create the member, then click on it and press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> :

[image]

Comment: That looks like what I want :) but a refactor only offer me to rename the field.
I'm using QT Creator 2.3.1, is that why ? Or is there something to do in the settings ?

Comment: @fxm well, I'm running 2.8.1, it might come from the gap between the two versions. I'll take a look, but maybe you should think about an update

Comment: Updating right now, didn't think there would be such a gap in the repository. Thanks for your answer anyway !

Comment: It look to me there is no such option in Qt creator 3.2.1, if there is some other way, please let me know

Answer (score 21):

Position your text cursor at the member variable in class definition, then hit Alt+Enter.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, running Qt Creator under Ubuntu 14 in a VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

For me, right-click, Refactor, Create Getter and Setter member functions works, except when the member is a bool.

Comment: i guess it is not very convenient when you change the property name

Answer (score 0):

Using macro, one can create getter, setter and signal together as follow :

```
#define GETSET(type, var) \
  protected: \
    type m##var; \
  public: \
    type Get##var() const \
    {\
      return m##var; \
    }\
    void Set##var(type iVal) \
    {\
      m##var = iVal; \
      var##Changed(iVal); \
    }
```

and calling the macro :

```
class Student : QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public signals:
    void NameChanged(const QString & name);
    void AddressChanged(const QString & address);
    void BirthDateChanged(const QDate & date);

  GETSET(QString, Name)
  GETSET(QString, Address)
  GETSET(QDate, BirthDate)
}
```

Comment: This code emits a `...Changed` signal every time the setter is called, while the Qt documentation (The Property System) clearly says: "The NOTIFY signal should only be emitted when the property has really been changed, to avoid bindings being unnecessarily re-evaluated in QML, for example."

Comment: you could simply check if the value has changed before emiting the signal